# Add subtitle to MP4 file with ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

my steps are like this

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -i subtitle.srt -c copy -c:s mov_text video-x.mp4

ffmpeg -i video-x.mp4 -codec: copy -bsf:v h264_mp4toannexb -start_number 0 -hls_time 10 -hls_list_size 0 -f hls hls/index.m3u8
```

But i have a error, "Could not write header for output file": [details of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Smo9i.png)

How would I resolve this problem?

Comment: A different subtitle codec is needed for HLS: `ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -i subtitle.srt -c:v copy -c:a copy -start_number 0 -hls_time 10 -hls_list_size 0 -f hls hls/index.m3u8`

Answer (score 0):

I want to embed the caption in the video, how can I do it?

[output of the above code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OmUuU.png)

Comment: Please note that this is not a "normal" forum formatted site. Answers are for answers. Please remove this and place it as a comment to your original question. Alternatively, you can edit your question to add new information and ask the commenter to review your updates.

Comment: And to be clear: as is, the person you are responding to will never be aware of this "response" post unless they come back to view the question on their own (unlikely). When you respond to their comment with your own, however, they will get a notification.